# How to find if url containing special characters or space exists in java

Tags: java, http, url, networking, file-exists

I have tried to find whether a url exists or not with the following code. The requirement is to find whether a file exists or not in the url.

```
    try{
         HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
         HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
         con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
         responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
         return Response.ok(Integer.toString(responseCode)).build();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return Response.ok(e.getMessage()).build();
    }
```

This works perfectly if the url doesn't contain any spaces/special characters. But if it has any, it always returns code 404. Can I know how this can be solved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're decoding first? If there are special characters in the url, they'll be decoded here, and cause the 404. You likely want to connect to the encoded url.

Comment: oops.. I forgot to remove that line. I have edited the program now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLs with spaces in them are invalid. The correct way to create a properly encoded URL from a filename that may contain spaces is  `URI.toASCIIString(),` and then passing that to `new URL(),` making sure to use a URI constructor that takes multiple arguments so the filename part gets encoded: see the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html).

However I question the requirement. The best way to test whether any resource is available is to try to use it. In this case presumably you are going to read from the URL if it exists, so just do that and catch the `FileNotFoundException`.